# How do I find the biggest possible product of two numbers in an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int product;
    int n;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    cout << "Enter the number of numbers you'll input: ";
    cin >> n;
    int numbers[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int m = 0; m < n; m++){
            if(i != m){
                product = numbers[m] * numbers[i];
                if(product < numbers[m - 1] * numbers[i] && i != m - 1){
                    product = numbers[m - 1] * numbers[i];
                    num1 = numbers[m - 1];
                    num2 = numbers[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "" << num1 << " " << num2 << "" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've been able to do so far. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't. It depends on the order of the numbers. I noticed that the product is the correct value but when I print the two numbers that get multiplied they aren't correct.

I want it to print the two numbers.

Comment: Instead, find the 2 largest positive and 2 most negative numbers by walking the list.  O(n).  Then determine greatest product.

Comment: "when I print the two numbers that get multiplied they aren't correct" --> post the 2 numbers and the product seen rather than only describe them.

Comment: I'm not sure what all those comparisons to `m-1` are doing in there. It looks like you overwrite the value of `product` without checking to see whether it's actually higher than the previous value in `product`? chux's suggestion seems much simpler.

Comment: *"It depends on the order of the numbers."* -If that is the case, your question should include an order of numbers that you *know* does *not* seem to print the desired results, ideally static-coded into the program so no input is required. All part of a proper [mcve].

Comment: In addition to the other comments, `int n; /*...*/ int numbers[n]` is not legal. `n` must be declared `constexpr` or be replaced with a literal value.

Comment: `product = numbers[m] * numbers[i];` is prone to overflow.  Better to use wider math.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you overwrite the product without checking and also you constantly calculate products regardless.
Just go through the Array once, on your way you compare for the smallest two negative numbers and same time for the largest positive numbers. In the end you are left with the factors forming the largest possible product from
either direction, this you only have to compare and automatically you held your factors too.